# VueJS, Symfony 6, Nginx and Docker CORS error

Tags: docker, symfony, nginx, docker-compose, cors

I'm trying to Dockerize a project, frontend and backend separated: if I start the two project (in the same root, but different folder) with commands to starty Symfony and VueJS it works fine.
But if I try to Dockerize everything, I get CORS errors.
I'm using:

- `Symfony 6.1`
- `Vue 3.2.13`
- `PHP 8.1`
- `Docker 4.24.2`

Inside the root project i got few files and 3 folders: client, server and nginx
This is the Docker from the server:

```
FROM php:8.1-fpm

# Copy composer.lock and composer.json into the working directory
COPY composer.lock composer.json /var/www/html/

# Set working directory
WORKDIR /var/www/html/

# Install dependencies for the operating system software
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    build-essential \
    libpng-dev \
    zip \
    vim \
    git \
    curl

# Install extensions for php
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql
RUN docker-php-ext-install gd

# Install composer (php package manager)
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer

# Copy existing application directory contents to the working directory
COPY . /var/www/html

# Expose port 7999 and start php-fpm server (for FastCGI Process Manager)
EXPOSE 7999

CMD ["php-fpm"]
```

And inside the .env file I got this line:

```
###> nelmio/cors-bundle ###
CORS_ALLOW_ORIGIN='^https?://(localhost|127\.0\.0\.1)(:[0-9]+)?$'
###< nelmio/cors-bundle ###
```

And inside config/packages/nelmio_cors.yaml

```
nelmio_cors:
    defaults:
        origin_regex: true
        allow_origin: ['%env(CORS_ALLOW_ORIGIN)%']
        allow_methods: ['GET', 'OPTIONS', 'POST', 'PUT', 'PATCH', 'DELETE']
        allow_headers: ['Content-Type', 'Authorization']
        expose_headers: ['Link']
        max_age: 3600
    paths:
        '^/': null
```

In the client part i got the Docker:

```
FROM node:16 as build-stage
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY ./ .
RUN npm run build

FROM nginx as production-stage
EXPOSE 3000
RUN mkdir /app
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY --from=build-stage /app/dist /app
```

And the nginx.conf

```
server {
  listen 3000;

  location / {
    root /app;
    index index.html index.htm;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
  }
}
```

In the nginx folder i got two file: this is the default.conf

```
upstream frontend {
  server frontend:3000;
}

#upstream backend {
  #server backend:7999;
#}

server {
  listen 80;
  index index.php index.html;
  error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
  access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
  root /var/www/html/public;

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://frontend;
  }

  location /api {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    gzip_static on;
  }

  # Nginx Pass requests to PHP-FPM
  location ~ \.php$ {
    #try_files $uri =404;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    #fastcgi_pass backend;
    fastcgi_pass localhost:7999;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
  }
}
```

And the Dockerfile is

```
FROM nginx
COPY ./default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
```

And finally in the root project, the docker-compose.yml is

```
version: '3.8'

x-common-variables: &common-variables
  MYSQL_DATABASE: $MYSQL_DATABASE
  MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: $MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD

services:
  db:
    image: mysql
    restart: always
    cap_add:
      - SYS_NICE
    volumes:
      - mysql_data:/var/lib/mysql
      - ./server/db-setup.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/setup.sql
    container_name: database
    ports:
      - "$DB_PORT:3306"
    environment:
      <<: *common-variables
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: $MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
      MYSQL_HOST: $MYSQL_HOST

  #Nginx Service
  nginx:
    depends_on:
      - backend
      - frontend
    restart: always
    build:
      context: ./nginx
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: nginx
    ports:
      - "8080:80"

  #PHP Service
  backend:
    build:
      context: ./server
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    depends_on:
      - db
    container_name: backend
    environment:
      <<: *common-variables
      SERVICE_NAME: backend
      PORT: $API_PORT
    volumes:
      - /server/:/var/www/html/
      - /var/www/html/vendor

  frontend:
    stdin_open: true
    container_name: frontend
    build:
      context: /client
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - /app/node_modules
      - /client:/var/www/html/
    ports:
      - $CLIENT_PORT:$CLIENT_PORT

  adminer:
    image: adminer:latest
    restart: unless-stopped
    container_name: database-view
    ports:
      - $ADMINER_PORT:8080
    depends_on:
      - db
    environment:
      ADMINER_DEFAULT_SERVER: db

volumes:
  mysql_data:
```

I'm either receiving CORS error or NS_ERROR_DOM_BAD_URI
[image]

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

I resolved by not using `php:8.1-fpm` in the Server Dockerfile and using `FROM php:8.1-apache`

```
FROM php:8.1-apache

# Copy composer.lock and composer.json into the working directory
COPY composer.lock /var/www
COPY composer.json /var/www

# Set working directory
WORKDIR /var/www/

# Install dependencies for the operating system software
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    build-essential \
    libpng-dev \
    zip \
    vim \
    git \
    curl 

# Install extensions for php
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql
RUN docker-php-ext-install mysqli && docker-php-ext-enable mysqli

# Install composer (php package manager)
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer

# Copy existing application directory contents to the working directory
COPY . /var/www
```

Then i added a `vhosts.conf` file inside a `vhosts` folder in server folder

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName localhost

    DocumentRoot /var/www/server/public
    DirectoryIndex /index.php

    <Directory /var/www/server/public>
        AllowOverride None
        Order Allow,Deny
        Allow from All

        FallbackResource /index.php
    </Directory>

    <Directory /var/www/server/public/bundles>
        FallbackResource disabled
    </Directory>
    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/server_error.log
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/server_access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

This way its a bit heavier since it's using apache, but its working